# Include specific file from exluding folder

Tags: linux, bash, sh, rhel

I am using rsyn to copy a folder from source to desination

I am able to use exclude successfully

```
$  rsync -av --exclude='*/deploy/scb_pdm/*' --exclude='*/logs/*'  $COPY_SRC_DIR  $COPY_DEST_DIR
```

> ```
> server-4.5.0/conf/wrapper.conf
> server-4.5.0/deploy/
> server-4.5.0/deploy/scb_pdm/
> server-4.5.0/deploy/scb_pdm/director.properties
> server-4.5.0/deploy/scb_pdm/ocollate_static.madconfig
> server-4.5.0/lib/
> server-4.5.0/lib/blue-marble-4.5.0.201511121524.jar
> ```

Now I am stuck, How can I exclude only

```
server-4.5.0/deploy/scb_pdm/ocollate_static.madconfig
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude the file in subdirectory right?

Comment: @ LethalProgrammer: yes

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with the generic usage of rsync to exclude the directory.

In order to achieve that you need to use `--exclude` flag.

```
rsync -arv --exclude cache/ your_src_dir/ your_dest_dir/
```

to your case, this will exclude the specific file that is `ocollate_static.madconfig`.

```
rsync -arv --exclude='*/deploy/scb_pdm/ocollate_static.madconfig*' --exclude='*/logs/*'  $COPY_SRC_DIR  $COPY_DEST_DIR
```

---

You can think of using another flag that is

```
--delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```

---

Another option, excluding multiple files and dirs at the same time.

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude your_file1.txt --exclude dir3/file4.txt source/ destination/
```

For detail information about using exclude in [rsync](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/?utm_source=feedburner).

Comment: It works. In this case, if I want only "server-4.5.0/deploy/scb_pdm/director.properties"   and not the "ocollate_static.madconfig"

Comment: I tried the same "rsync -arv --include='*/deploy/scb_pdm/director.properties*' --exclude='*/logs/*'  $COPY_SRC_DIR  $COPY_DEST_DIR". But it worked :(